# list items along side images in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to use images alongside the list items in navigation bar just like in the picture below I have used table also but can't able to get the output .i've also tried to do it by using img tag directly inside ul tag. but still not working. please help.
CSS

```
/* Sub-menu */
#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;    
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 35;
z-index: 99999;    
background-color: #444;   
background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu ul img{position: relative; float: right; width:100px; height:100px;left:100px; bottom: 50px; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 
            0 2px 0 #777777;     background-color: #444;   
background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
 display: block;  }
```

HTML

```
<body><ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Categories</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Development tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
        <img src="footer.png" >
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to putting your list into one `div` and your `img` in another. see https://jsfiddle.net/cpee7v11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` for the image and for the `ul` use `pagging-right` with the width of image and `min-height` with the height of image to be sure that the ul will always contain the image . https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/7kvc5avh/

```
#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;    
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 35;
z-index: 99999;    
background-color: #444;   
background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-right:120px;
min-height:120px;
}
#menu ul img{
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  right:10px;
  top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 
    0 2px 0 #777777;
  background-color: #444;   
  background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate Its been really a great help